# Discrete Mathematics - Direct Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given

Prove the statement, for all integers $n$ if $5n$ is odd, then $n$ is odd

We know that this is not true for $n=4$ simply by building a table for values for $n$ and $5n$...

Is that all I need to do? I've shown a table up to $n=4$ and, by contradiction of the original statement, $n$ is even and $5n$ is even.

Comment: $5n \equiv n \mod 2$

Comment: Thanks for that! Have I satisfied the question?

Comment: It is true for $n=4$.  $5\cdot 4$ is *even*, so the antecedant is false and therefore the conditional is true..

Answer (score 1):

> We know that this is not true for $ n=4$

We don't know that, at all.   The statement "*If* $5n$ is odd, *then* $n$ is odd," will only be falsified should there be some integer $n$ where $5n$ is *odd* and $n$ is *even*.   You have an *even* $n$ but so is $5n$.   That does *not* contradict the conditional.

So you could prove by contradiction, that if $n$ is even, then $5n$ will be.   However, you asked for a *direct proof*.

---

**Directly:**

For any integer n, then "$5n$ is odd" means exactly that there exists an integer $k$ such that $5n=2k+1$.   This algebraically rearranges to $n=2(k-2n)+1$.

Now, if $k$, $2$, and $n$ are integers, then ....

Answer (score 0):

The statement 'If $5n$ is odd, then $n$ is odd' is logically *equivalent* to the statement 'If $n$ is even, then $5n$ is even'. So, the $n=4$ case is not at all contradicting the claim, but is compatible with it.

In fact, the claim is true, and your task is to prove it is true for all $n$. Making a table for just a few values of $n$ will not show that.

HINT

As I just pointed out, the claim is equivalent to 'If $n$ is even, then $5n$ is even' ... Can you prove that?

Comment: So for $n\geq4$ in some iterative scheme, summation.

Answer (score 0):

Well if 5n is odd think about the multiplication of two odds .What is the result ? Odd or even ? And 5 is odd...and 5n by hypothesis is odd too..

let's consider s odd and t odd too. Multiply both numbers st, and see what you get..

$ s=2k+1, t=2j+1 $

$ st= (2h+1)(2j+1)= 4hj+2h+2j+1 $ therefore (st) is odd

I don't really underrstand what's the purpose of the table ? Maybe I'm missing the point. Just consider 5n as odd , remember that 5 is odd and suppose n even then show a contradiction with that hypothesis on n.